# Count and return number of nosetests

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

I have a set of unit test scripts saved in the pwd.  I would like to be able to count the number of unit tests (`nosetests`) that would be executed (without actually executing them) and return that number into a python variable like this:

```
>>> number_of_unit_tests = count_unit_tests('.')
>>> number_of_unit_tests

400
```

I know I can collect from the command line like this:

```
nosetests --collect-only
```

But is it possible to do this from within a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the any nose command form python script, as described in [basic nose usage](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#basic-usage), the only trick would be to extract the number of tests. I took a look at [functional tests in nose](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/blob/master/functional_tests/test_program.py) and figured something like this should work, but you might be able to trim it down further:

```
import sys
import unittest
from cStringIO import StringIO

import nose
from nose.result import _TextTestResult


class TestRunner(unittest.TextTestRunner):
    def _makeResult(self):
        self.result = _TextTestResult(
            self.stream, self.descriptions, self.verbosity)
        return self.result


def count_unit_tests(module_name):
    stream = StringIO()
    runner = TestRunner(stream=stream)

    result = nose.run(
        testRunner=runner,
        argv=[sys.argv[0],
              module_name,
              '-s',
              '-v',
              '--collect-only'
        ]
    )

    return runner.result.testsRun

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print count_unit_tests('.')
```